# How to get save as dialog in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, save

How do I make a "save as" dialog in MFC?

For example, when I click "save as" in MFC, a dialog appears. How do I replicate that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example from MSDN for an open dialog box :

```
void CMyClass::OnFileOpen()
{
   // szFilters is a text string that includes two file name filters:
   // "*.my" for "MyType Files" and "*.*' for "All Files."
   TCHAR szFilters[]= _T("MyType Files (*.my)|*.my|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");

   // Create an Open dialog; the default file name extension is ".my".
   CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, _T("my"), _T("*.my"),
      OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, szFilters);

   // Display the file dialog. When user clicks OK, fileDlg.DoModal() 
   // returns IDOK.
   if(fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
   {
      CString pathName = fileDlg.GetPathName();

      // Implement opening and reading file in here.

      //Change the window's title to the opened file's title.
      CString fileName = fileDlg.GetFileTitle();

      SetWindowText(fileName);
   }
}
```

For the Save As dialog box, just change the CFileDialog call by :

```
   CFileDialog fileDlg(FALSE, _T("my"), _T("*.my"),
        OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, szFilters);
```

Remarks:

- Some arguments are optional.
- **szFilters** contains the file extensions you need.

Comment: In the case of Save As, OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST should not be used. OTOH, OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT is most likely wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
CFileDialog dlg(FALSE);
dlg.DoModal();
```

Comment: How to get all the file extension in one line?